# Angular cross-domain post: fails using some browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, cross-domain

I have a cross-domain POST request in Angular (1.4.0), which works using Chrome (43+) and Firefox (37+) after I remove the Content-Type header.

But it fails when using Safari, or Safari/Chrome on the iPhone/iPad.
The error message then is:

> Failed to load resource: Request header field Content-Type is not
>   allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

But in the log I can see:

```
[Log] original httpProvider defaults (app.js, line 6)
[Log] Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8 (app.js, line 7)
[Log] updated httpProvider defaults (app.js, line 13)
[Log] Content-Type: undefined (app.js, line 14)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (search, line 0)
...
headers: Object
  Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
```

So: an error message even though there is no Content-Type in the header.

**Any suggestions?**

Snippet:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    console.log("original httpProvider defaults");
    console.log("Content-Type:", $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type']);

    //$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    //delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'];

    console.log("updated httpProvider defaults");
    console.log("Content-Type:", $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type']);
}]);

app.controller('testController', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
    console.log("testController");

    $scope.url = "http://.../v0/search";
    $scope.data = { "query":"auto" };

    $scope.testPost = function() {
        $http.post($scope.url, $scope.data).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data, status, headers, config);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data, status, headers, config);
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to have bothered you, it was a server issue after all. The API provider has updated their API and now it works.

I am still somewhat curious what could cause the server to treat the same request differently from the various browsers, 
and I don't really understand the error message when logging tells me that that header field was not set.
But it is working now and that is what counts most.